# How to add an "_blank" attribute inside ajax code?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm really a beginner in ajax/jquery. I need to open a link in a new window like "target=_blank" but my code only makes the link to open in the same window. I have tried different things like inserting target _blank inside the jquery but it didn't work at all. I really appreciate any help [:)

```
function initHeroSwitch() {
var heroCnt = $('#hero ul li').size();
if ($('#hero').length > 0) {
    $('#hero').append('<div id="hero-btns"></div>');
    $('#hero ul li').each(function (index) { 
$('#hero-btns').append('<a href="" rel="' + (index) +   '"></a>'); });

    $('#hero ul li').each(function () {
        getRel = $(this).attr('rel');
        winHeight = $(window).height();
        if (winHeight > 750) {
            var bkgImg = getRel.split('.');
            bkgImg = bkgImg[0];
            bkgImg = bkgImg.substr(0, bkgImg.length - 3);
            bkgImg = bkgImg + "-lg.jpg";
            $('#hero ul li').each(function () { preload(bkgImg); });
        } else {
            preload(getRel);
        }
    });
    startHeroRotate();
    rotateHero(rotateSpeed);
} else { autoRotate = window.setInterval(function () { startNewsRotation(); }, rotateSpeed); }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Hvae you tried this:

```
$('#hero-btns').append('<a href="" target="_blank" rel="' + (index) +   '"></a>');
```

Comment: hey mrchief, thanks for trying but i've already tried this ....the thing is when i click a link it should be opened in a new window but the way it is now the redirection appends to my host in the same window, and weirdly when i click the back button it automatically go to the link again o_O

Comment: That sounds like something on the page is acting globally. Can you post your markup and more details as to who is doing the redirect and how?